# Defined function is not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which is called in a for loop.

```
 function printResult(name, i) {

$('#list').append("<a href='#' onClick='goto(" + i + ");' class='item'><H1>" + name + "</H1>    </a>");
 }
```

The a href-tags are appended as they should, but when I call the goto function firebug says: 'goto is not defined'

But it is!!

This is the function:

```
function goto(myPoint){
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(marker[myPoint-1].position.lat(), marker[myPoint-      
      1].position.lng()));
     markerArr[myPoint-1]['infowindow'].open(map, markerArr[myPoint-1]);
  }
```

I'm clueless as to why the function is not found. Does it have something to do with it being called in the appended  a href-tag?

Comment: Ok, could you elaborate?

Comment: it is a scope issue. I need the code that shows how both functions are defined and in what scope. Is goto() a closue in some other function or it is defined in the global scope? Try defining it as window.goto = function ( myPoint ) {} (in the global) and make sure it is defined BEFORE the call to printResult() function.

Comment: Ok, I suspected it had soemthing to do with this. I will go through the code and see what I can find in terms of scope problems. I'll let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

`goto()` is a terrible name for a function, because it's commonly used as a keyword in a lot of programming languages.

In Javascript, it is not a keyword. However, it *is* [a reserved word](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm), on the grounds that it may be used in future versions of the language. This alone may be causing JS to reject your function or fail to call it.

But even if it weren't a reserved, is could be seen as a potential ambiguity, and so would not be recommended for use.

Therefore, my suggestion would be to change the function name. With luck, it might magically start working.

Comment: This makes no effort at actually answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you define event handlers by using `onclick` attributes, the definition of `goto()` **must be global**, i.e. `window.goto` must exist.

More importantly, **this is not the jQuery way**; event handlers should be defined in JavaScript code rather than HTML.

```
function printResult(name, i) 
{
    var $title = $('<h1 />', { text: name }),
    $anchor = $('<a href="#" class="item" />')
        .append($title)
        .on('click', {
            index: i
        }, moveToIndex)
        .appendTo('#list');
}

// this is the click handler
function moveToIndex(evt)
{
    // evt.data.index = the value of i
}
```

I have renamed your `goto()` function into `moveToIndex()` which is somewhat more descriptive. This should not have the same scope issues as your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery click events like this:

Html:

```
function printResult(name, i) {
    $('#list').append("<a href='#' rel='" + i + "' class='item'><H1>" + name + "</H1></a>");
}
```

Js:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.item', function (e) {
   goto($(this).attr("rel"));
});
```

But I recommend to  rename the function `goto` to something else or do:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.item', function (e) {
   var myPoint = $(this).attr("rel");
   map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(marker[myPoint-1].position.lat(), marker[myPoint-      
  1].position.lng()));
   markerArr[myPoint-1]['infowindow'].open(map, markerArr[myPoint-1]);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You are using `onClick='goto(" + i + ");'`. Use `onclick ='goto("+i+")'` instead, don't use a semicolon

Comment: what is the difference? [Semicolons in JavaScript are optional](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/)

Comment: The semicolon is irrelevant (and may actually be a good thing in some circumstances). Removing it won't make any difference at all.